# Scraping an html with Swift 4 in Xcode 9

Tags: html, ios, parsing, swift4, xcode9

Ok I have a website I want to scrape for specific links.
I already used URLSession to put all websites contents into a string.
Now I have to get all Links into an array which have the following structure:

"<   a href="/thisIsAlwaysTheSame/ThisIsAUniqueNumber/ThisIsWhatIDontNeed..."

So that I get an array: [href="/thisIsAlwaysTheSame/UniqueNumberA/, href="/thisIsAlwaysTheSame/UniqueNumberB, href="/thisIsAlwaysTheSame/UniqueNumberC, etc.]"
There are many more links on the website, but I only need those which have this format.
Optionally I would also be happy if I get only the UniqueNumbers into an array.

I already asked this question on reddit, but didn't get sufficient answers:
https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/7256vi/scraping_an_html_with_swift_4_in_xcode_9/

Here is what I know already from my research and the answers on reddit already:

- "Kanna" is suggested --> I can't get it running in Xcode 9 (I already opened an issue on GitHub)
- SwiftSoup could be an option --> Same problem like Kanna, can't get it running in Xcode 9 (I also opened an Issue on Github)
- I got the advice that I can solve my problem with the Swift string class reading up following link:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string --> I read it but don't really see how I can solve my problem with these methods. Perhaps I am missing something there?

Any advice? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used following code after adding SwiftSoup:

```
guard let linkElements: Elements = try SwiftSoup.parse(myLinkHTMLContent).select("a")  else {return}
//  Now all elements are printed into an array
for element: Element in linkElements.array(){
myLinksArray.append("\(element)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to extract all URLs from a HTML String. You can do so by adding a loop which checks the String for any URLs:

```
let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
let matches = detector.matches(in: content, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: content.utf16.count))
for match in matches {
    let url = (content as NSString).substring(with: match.range)
    if url.contains("ThisIsWhatIDontNeed") {
        //do smtg
    } else {
        self.img_urls.append(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it and keep you updated!

Comment: Just want to update - I found a solution with another approach but thanks for answering!

Comment: @MakiCodes Can you write your solution for this problem !

Comment: @FadyLateef I will loock it up again!

Comment: @FadyLateef see my answer!